# How to find tangential and normal unit vector to a trajectory from the equation?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, acceleration, vectors

Considering a 2D motion in a plane and the equation of the trajectory of a point $y=f(x)$, I don't understand how exactly $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$ can be used.

In particular if I'm looking for the tangential acceleration, I need the tangential unit vector $u_T$.

Since

$$\lvert\vec{v}_y \rvert=\frac{\mathrm{d}f(x(t))}{\mathrm{d}t}=\frac{\mathrm{d}f(x)}{\mathrm{d}x} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}=\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} \lvert \vec{v}_x \rvert$$

Can I conclude that

$$u_T=\frac{\vec{v}}{\lvert\vec{v}\rvert}=\frac{u_x+\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}u_y}{\sqrt{1+\bigl(\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}\bigr)^2}}$$

If so, can I do something similar for trajectories (like circles) in the form $f(x,y)=0$?

Furthermore how can I get the normal unit vector $u_N$ (for istance to find the normal acceleration) from the $u_T$ previously found?

I know that $u_N=\frac{\mathrm{d}u_T/\mathrm{d}t}{\lvert\mathrm{d}u_T/\mathrm{d}t\rvert}$ but the derivative is with respect to time here.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Given a planar vector $(e_x,e_y)$ the normal direction is $(-e_y,e_x)$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tangential acceleration in circular motion?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/99566/)

Answer (score 1):

At every point the tangential direction is the unit vector of the velocity vector. If you have the velocity components $\boldsymbol{v} = (\dot{x}, \dot{y})$ at every instant, the you decompose this into a magnitude (speed $v$) and direction $\hat{\boldsymbol{e}}$

$$ \begin{align} v & = \sqrt{\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2} \\
\hat{\boldsymbol{e}} & = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{\dot{x}}{v} & \frac{\dot{y}}{v} \end{pmatrix} \\  \boldsymbol{v} & = v\; \hat{\boldsymbol{e}} \end{align} $$

The normal direction is simply

$$ \hat{\boldsymbol{n}} = \begin{pmatrix} -\frac{\dot{y}}{v} & \frac{\dot{x}}{v} \end{pmatrix} $$

Answer (score 0):

The easy way of doing this is to parametrice the trajectory. We have the cartesian definition, so let $ \textbf{r} : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow {\mathbb{R}}^{2} $ be:
$$
\textbf{r}(t)=(t,f(t)) \quad\quad t\in (-\infty,\infty)
$$

So we got the vector position as function of "time". Then, the velocity and acceleration vectors are defined by:
$$
\textbf{v}(t)=\frac{d}{dt}\textbf{r}(t) \quad \quad \textbf{a}(t)=\frac{d}{dt}\textbf{v}(t)
$$

Now, you can get the tangential acceleration with the projection over the velocity, that is always tangential to the trajectory:
$$
{a}_{t}=\textbf{a} \cdot \frac{\textbf{v}}{v}
$$
Where $v$ is the length of the velocity vector.