# What happens to $A$'s magnitude change in uniform circular motion?

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-mechanics

[image]

Looking at this picture from Kleppner's mechanics text, Δa is added to $A$ and it is suggested that:

> "This causes a change of direction but leaves the magnitude practically unaltered if $ΔA$ is small."

What is practically happening in this sense? When looking at it from a calculus perspective, this makes total sense and the math lines up...but looking at it from a physical perspective my intuition tells me there is some sort of 'stretching' that goes on in the arm/bar/thread that is being rotated via perpendicular force (taking into account friction, a constant force must be needed to maintain uniform velocity).

In a real scenario, what is this 'stretching'? At some point does the arm break?
What if we are dealing with the rotation of a particle via an applied field? What is the 'stretching' that goes on here?

Comment: You need to define your terms better. According to the picture it looks like $\Delta A$ is added to $A$. So what is $da/dt$ that you mention in the text? And what exactly is the $r$ that you mention in the question title? Is it the sequence of $A,A',A'',A''',\ldots$ as a function of time?

Comment: Somehow you expect the reader to have Kleppers mechanic book at hand. It seems you are talking about circular motion of a  arm/bar/thread ?

Comment: @CuspyCode, edited the question to make it consistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Uniform circular motion dilemma](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/279769/uniform-circular-motion-dilemma)
I think this link answers my question and provides some good examples of effects of force as well.