# How do I derive the formula for radial acceleration when there is no uniform circular motion?

Tags: kinematics, vectors, angular-velocity

My lecturer states that $a_r=\dfrac{v_t^2}{r}=\omega^2r$ where $v_t$ is tangential velocity, he also wrote that this is derived the same way that radial acceleration is derived in uniform circular motion.

I know the derivation for uniform circular motion but I simply can't see how the derivation can be the same for non uniform motion. (the derivation I know is the graphical one where you manipulate the infinitesimal velocity and angular position.)

Comment: Differentiate $\vec{r}=r\hat{r}$ twice with respect to time, taking care to consider the derivative of $\hat{r}$. You’ll find both the radial and the tangential acceleration.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proof of centripetal acceleration formula ($a_c = v^2/r$) for non-uniform circular motion](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/121535/)

Answer (score 1):

For a non-uniform circular motion your graphical demonstration remains valid. Simply, $\frac{d\theta}{dt}=\omega$ is no longer constant in time. You could write $\omega(t)$ to make it explicitly time-dependent.

Comment: But, if you use the graphical method, then when you do v(final)-v(initial) after dt time , the vector dv is not in same direction like the radial acceleration. Vector dv has direction =a(tangential)+a(radial) isn't it ?

Comment: Yes you're right! I have probably overlooked the difficulty of deriving it from a graphical method. You should probably follow a more general demonstration in this case, as suggested by G. Smith.