# Can average acceleration be exactly determined from discrete points separated by equal time intervals?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, velocity, projectile, estimation

I am using the American dialect of the English language. The following definitions distinguish my question from the similar, previously asked question:

https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=approximation

> 2. Mathematics An **inexact result** adequate for a given purpose.

https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=average

> 1. Mathematics a. A number that typifies a set of numbers of which **it is a function**.

My question: **is there an *exact expression* for the time-average
of acceleration in terms of projectile position coordinates measured
at instants in time separated by a constant, known time period?**

I am **not** asking how to approximate acceleration based on
this data. Though I am interested in that matter as well.

I am writing a short discussion of projectile motion, primarily for
my own edification. I had originally intended to give exact expressions
for both average velocity and average acceleration, based on my hypothetical
input data. After playing with the math a bit, it occurred to
me that it is not possible to give such an exact formulation of average
acceleration. I wish to say as much in my essay, but it seems prudent
to verify the fact before committing it to an affirmative statement.

By *an exact expression for the time average of acceleration*, I mean an 
expression similar to that used below to define the time-average of velocity.

The following is my method of approximating the acceleration
near the times $t_{p}:$

Two-dimensional projectile position coordinates
are recorded at instants in time denoted by

$$
t_{p}=p\Delta t,
$$

where $p$ is an integer index increasing with time, and $\Delta t$
is a fixed time increment. These *known* coordinates are written

$$
\mathfrak{r}_{p}=\begin{bmatrix}y_{p}\\
z_{p}
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

We assume projectile coordinates have some *unknown* functional
dependence on time, denoted by
$$
\mathfrak{r}\left[t\right]=\begin{bmatrix}y\left[t\right]\\
z\left[t\right]
\end{bmatrix},\text{ and }\mathfrak{r}_{p}=\mathfrak{r}\left[t_{p}\right];
$$

where $\mathfrak{r}\left[t\right]$ is sufficiently differentiable.
Projectile displacement during a time interval $\Delta t_{p}=\left[\left(p-1\right)\Delta t,p\Delta t\right]=\left[t_{p-1},t_{p}\right]$
is determined from these measurements to be
$$
\Delta\mathfrak{r}_{p}=\mathfrak{r}_{p}-\mathfrak{r}_{p-1}.
$$
 The *time-average of velocity* over a time interval $\Delta t_{p}$
is *defined* by the equation

$$
\left\langle \mathfrak{v}_{p}\right\rangle \equiv\frac{\Delta\mathfrak{r}_{p}}{\Delta t}.
$$

First, suppose $\Delta t$ is large compared to changes in the actual
velocity; which we denote as the *unknown* differentiable function
of time,
$$
\mathfrak{v}\left[t\right]=\frac{d\mathfrak{r}}{dt}\left[t\right].
$$

Hypothetically, velocity could be zero over most of an interval $\Delta t_{p},$
then change rapidly during some small final sub-interval, so that
the entire displacement $\Delta\mathfrak{r}_{p}$ occurs in that final
period. In such a case the time-average of velocity over the entire
interval $\Delta t_{p}$ will not equal the numerical average of the
velocities at the endpoints:

$$
\left\langle \mathfrak{v}_{p}\right\rangle \ne\frac{\mathfrak{v}_{p-1}+\mathfrak{v}_{p}}{2}=\mathfrak{v}_{p-1}+\frac{\Delta\mathfrak{v}_{p}}{2}.
$$

Alternatively, if velocity were to change with time at a constant
rate

$$
\frac{d\mathfrak{v}}{dt}=\mathfrak{a}\text{, so that}
$$

$$
\mathfrak{v}\left[t\right]=\mathfrak{v}_{0}+t\mathfrak{a},\text{ and}
$$

$$
\mathfrak{v}_{p}-\mathfrak{v}_{p-1}=\Delta t\mathfrak{a}=\Delta\mathfrak{v}_{p}=\Delta\mathfrak{v},
$$

we would find that

$$
\left\langle \mathfrak{v}_{p}\right\rangle =\mathfrak{v}_{p-1}+\frac{\mathfrak{v}_{p}-\mathfrak{v}_{p-1}}{2}=\mathfrak{v}_{p-1}+\frac{\Delta t}{2}\mathfrak{a}
$$

$$
=\mathfrak{v}_{p}-\Delta\mathfrak{v}_{p}+\frac{\Delta t}{2}\mathfrak{a}=\mathfrak{v}_{p}-\frac{\Delta t}{2}\mathfrak{a}.
$$
 In such a case the exact relationships

$$
\left\langle \mathfrak{v}_{p}\right\rangle =\mathfrak{v}\left[t_{p}-\frac{\Delta t}{2}\right]=\mathfrak{v}_{p}-\frac{\Delta t}{2}\mathfrak{a},\text{ and}
$$

$$
\left\langle \mathfrak{v}_{p+1}\right\rangle =\mathfrak{v}\left[t_{p}+\frac{\Delta t}{2}\right]=\mathfrak{v}_{p}+\frac{\Delta t}{2}\mathfrak{a}
$$

would hold. Thus, in the case of constant acceleration,
$$
\frac{\left\langle \mathfrak{v}_{p+1}\right\rangle -\left\langle \mathfrak{v}_{p}\right\rangle }{\Delta t}=\mathfrak{a}=\mathfrak{a}_{p}.
$$

Still assuming constant acceleration; position as a function of time
with constants $\mathfrak{r}_{0},\mathfrak{v}_{0},\mathfrak{a},$is
written

$$
\mathfrak{r}\left[t\right]=\mathfrak{r}_{0}+\mathfrak{v}_{0}t+\frac{1}{2}\mathfrak{a}t^{2},\text{ and}
$$

$$
\mathfrak{r}_{p}=\mathfrak{r}_{0}+\mathfrak{v}_{0}p\Delta t+\frac{1}{2}\mathfrak{a}\left(p\Delta t\right)^{2}
$$

$$
=\mathfrak{r}_{p-1}+\mathfrak{v}_{p-1}\Delta t+\frac{1}{2}\mathfrak{a}\Delta t^{2}.\text{ So that}
$$

$$
\Delta\mathfrak{r}_{p}=\mathfrak{r}_{p}-\mathfrak{r}_{p-1}=\left(\mathfrak{v}_{p-1}+\frac{\Delta t}{2}\mathfrak{a}\right)\Delta t
$$

$$
=\left(\mathfrak{v}_{p}-\frac{\Delta t}{2}\mathfrak{a}\right)\Delta t,\text{ and}
$$

$$
\Delta\mathfrak{r}_{p+1}=\mathfrak{r}_{p+1}-\mathfrak{r}_{p}=\left(\mathfrak{v}_{p}+\frac{\Delta t}{2}\mathfrak{a}\right)\Delta t.
$$

Taking the difference $\Delta\mathfrak{r}_{p+1}-\Delta\mathfrak{r}_{p},$
then dividing both sides by $\Delta t;$ upon applying the definition
of average velocity we arrive at

$$
\left\langle \mathfrak{v}_{p+1}\right\rangle -\left\langle \mathfrak{v}_{p}\right\rangle =\frac{\Delta\mathfrak{r}_{p+1}-\Delta\mathfrak{r}_{p}}{\Delta t}
$$

$$
=\left(\mathfrak{v}_{p}+\frac{\Delta t}{2}\mathfrak{a}\right)-\left(\mathfrak{v}_{p}-\frac{\Delta t}{2}\mathfrak{a}\right)
$$

$$
=\Delta t\mathfrak{a}.
$$

Dividing by $\Delta t$ again gives us an expression for the acceleration
in terms of our known data:

$$
\mathfrak{a}_{p}=\mathfrak{a}=\frac{\left\langle \mathfrak{v}_{p+1}\right\rangle -\left\langle \mathfrak{v}_{p}\right\rangle }{\Delta t}
$$

$$
=\frac{1}{\Delta t}\left(\frac{\Delta\mathfrak{r}_{p+1}}{\Delta t}-\frac{\Delta\mathfrak{r}_{p}}{\Delta t}\right)
$$

$$
=\frac{1}{\Delta t^{2}}\left(\begin{bmatrix}y_{p+1}-y_{p}\\
z_{p+1}-z_{p}
\end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix}y_{p}-y_{p-1}\\
z_{p}-z_{p-1}
\end{bmatrix}\right)
$$

$$
=\frac{1}{\Delta t^{2}}\left(\mathfrak{r}_{p+1}+\mathfrak{r}_{p-1}-2\mathfrak{r}_{p}\right).
$$

Now we consider the case in which the acceleration changes with time,
but the time increment $\Delta t$ is small in comparison to the acceleration.
Our assumption of sufficient differentiability for $\mathfrak{r}$
insures us that the velocity near $\mathfrak{r}_{p}$ is linear to
the first order in time. Thus our previous result provides a good
approximation for the acceleration at $t_{p}:$

$$
\mathfrak{a}_{p}\approx\frac{1}{\Delta t^{2}}\left(\mathfrak{r}_{p+1}+\mathfrak{r}_{p-1}-2\mathfrak{r}_{p}\right).
$$

**This is an approximation of acceleration, not a precisely defined
average.**

Comment: I don't know the answer, but it is possible to prove it for simple examples. Take a function $x(t)$ and discretize it, and calculate. I think there is something interesting with velocity, but calculations are needed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to approximate acceleration from a trajectory's coordinates?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/129701/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between *an approximation of acceleration* and *an exact formulation of average acceleration* can be seen by observing that thee data points are sufficient to approximate instantaneous acceleration; a formulation of average acceleration requires a minimum of four data points.

That I have provided distinct expressions for these distinct quantities *should* be sufficient to convince the qualified reader of the distinction between these similar concepts.

The answer is: *Yes*, it is *possible* to formulate an exact expression which can reasonably be called *average acceleration*.  What I have called the approximate acceleration at time $t_p$ is an exactly defined value derived from two average velocities.  Applying the same method to two consecutive "approximate" accelerations gives the two forms

$$\left\langle \mathfrak{a}_{p}\right\rangle \equiv\frac{\mathfrak{a}_{p}-\mathfrak{a}_{p-1}}{\Delta t}$$

$$=\frac{1}{\Delta t^{2}}\left(\left\langle \mathfrak{v}_{p+1}\right\rangle -2\left\langle \mathfrak{v}_{p}\right\rangle +\left\langle \mathfrak{v}_{p-1}\right\rangle \right)$$

$$=\frac{1}{\Delta t^{3}}\left(\mathfrak{r}_{p+1}+3\left(\mathfrak{r}_{p-1}-\mathfrak{r}_{p}\right)-\mathfrak{r}_{p-2}\right).$$

I'm not convinced of the utility of this expression, but it is an exact formulation consisting entirely of the input data, having a form similar to that used for average velocity.

I strongly urge anyone wishing to borrow this result to double-check my algebra and reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

With three points you must assume a constant acceleration. Then this problem becomes a problem of fitting a parabola through three points. The general solution is given by the [Lagrange interpolation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) where the 3-point acceleration is

$$a=2\dfrac{\frac{x_3-x_2}{t_3-t_2}-\frac{x_2-x_1}{t_2-t_1}}{t_3-t_1}=\dfrac{v_2-v_1}{\frac{t_3-t_1}{2}}$$

This matches the solution in your question.

Also a very practical analytic and graphical solution for experimental data points is given by [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/lac2i0bgum).

Answer (score 0):

You have a series of $x$ and $y$ values in a table (as well as time), and you want to calculate a cubic spline through the points. This will give you the velocities and acceleration (components) at each time frame.

> See [scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline.html)
>
> Then use the `.Derivative()` method to get what you want.

<sub>Ref [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2388449/3301)</sub>